# Utilizando Thymeleaf em código Java Script

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Boa noite amigos,

Eu tinha um extrato de código javascript usando tags JSP que gerava um gráfico de pizza e funciona corretamente. Preciso agora migrar para Thymeleaf e não faço a mínima idéia de como escrever o código. O codigo javascript com o JSP está assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);

  function drawChartPie() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Conta', 'Valor'],         
        <c:forEach items="${model.contaCorretora }" var="contaCorretora">
      ['${contaCorretora.tipoConta}', ${contaCorretora.valorAtual}],
    </c:forEach>
      ]);

    var options = {
      title: '${model.pessoa.nome }'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, você pode utilizar o Inline para Javascript, desta forma você pode acessar as variáveis da view diretamente dentro do código JS. Por exemplo:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  ...

  var titulo = [[${model.pessoa.nome}]];

  ...
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!
Eu fiz algo parecido para passar uma base64 para o JS vindo de um thymeleaf. Veja:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  var livro_pdf = /*[[${livro.pdf_string}]]*/ "Livro";
/*]]>*/

window.downloadPDF = function downloadPDF() {

    var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
    dlnk.href = pdf;

    dlnk.click();


    alert('Download Realizado com Sucesso!');
}
var b64 = document.getElementsByName('livro').value;
var pdf = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + livro_pdf;

</script>
```